# Slick DBIO to Future[Either[Error, User]]

Tags: scala, sbt, slick, slick-3.0

I am new to Slick and I have the issue below. 
I am trying to implement the method `createUser` as is defined here

```
def createUser(data: UserCreate): Future[User] = {
   val userRow = User(userId = UUID.randomUUID(),
     email = data.email, password = data.password,
     firstName = data.firstName, lastName = data.lastName, balance = 0)
   val userAction =
     Users
       .filter(_.email === data.email).result.headOption.flatMap {
       case Some(res) =>
         //          mylog("product was there: " + product)
           DBIO.successful(res)
       case None =>
         //          mylog("inserting product")
         (Users returning Users.map(_.id) into (
           (user, newId) => user.copy(id = Some(newId)))
           ) += userRow
     }
       .transactionally
   db.run(userAction)
}
```

The problem is that in case of the user is already exists I want to give an error, so the signature of the method should be

```
def createUser(data: UserCreate): Future[Either[RecordAlreadyExists, User]]
```

May you have any idea on how can I do it? without raise a Throwable?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is a case of transforming `Future`s rather than a question about slick.

How about something along the lines of:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case object RecordAlreadyExists extends RuntimeException

case class User(id: Int)

Future[User](throw new RuntimeException).
  transformWith {
  case Success(user) => Future.successful(Right[RecordAlreadyExists.type, User](user))
  case Failure(_) => Future.successful(Left[RecordAlreadyExists.type, User](RecordAlreadyExists))
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
defined object RecordAlreadyExists
defined class User
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Either[RecordAlreadyExists.type,User]] = Future(<not completed>)
```

instead of the catch-all that I have you could match on the specific DB exception that would signify "user already exists"

Note:
In my example `Future[User](throw new RuntimeException)` stands in for your complete function as specified in the question.